# Error message prevents access to WP

Tags: errors, debug

This message appears

```
Attempt to create object of class W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew has been made, but file /home/***/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_WpdbNew.php doesnt exists
#0 w3tc_class_autoload(W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew)
#1 spl_autoload_call(W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew) called at [/home/***/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_Wpdb.php:41]
#2 W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb::instance() called at [/home/***/wp-content/db.php:41]
#3 require_once(/home/***/wp-content/db.php) called at [/home/***/wp-includes/load.php:413] #4 require_wp_db() called at [/home/***/wp-settings.php:116]
#5 require_once(/home/***/wp-settings.php) called at [/home/***/wp-config.php:101]
#6 require_once(/home/***/wp-config.php) called at [/home/***/wp-load.php:37]
#7 require_once(/home/***/wp-load.php) called at [/home/***/wp-admin/admin.php:34]
#8 require_once(/home/***/wp-admin/admin.php) called at [/home/***/wp-admin/index.php:10]

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew' not found in /home/***/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_Wpdb.php:41 Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/wp-content/db.php(41): W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb::instance()
#1 /home/***/wp-includes/load.php(413): require_once('/home/luminiso/...')
#2 /home/***/wp-settings.php(116): require_wp_db()
#3 /home/***/wp-config.php(101): require_once('/home/luminiso/...')
#4 /home/***/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/luminiso/...') #5 /home/***/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/luminiso/...')
#6 /home/***/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/luminiso/...')
#7 {main} thrown in /home/***/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/DbCache_Wpdb.php on line 41

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in /home/***/wp-includes/formatting.php:4305 Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(190): esc_url('https://wordpre...')
#1 /home/***/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false)
#2 /home/***/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false)
#3 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown in /home/***/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4305
```

Comment: Try to remove the W3total cache plugin from the plugins directory.